conversion (and manipulation) of variadic template arguments into std::initialiser_list
I have reworked a function
void func(std::initializer_list<const char*> msgList);

into
void func(std::initializer_list<std::string_view> msgList);

(optimization, less strlen calls) which is implemented in a .cpp
void func (std::initializer_list<std::string_view> msgList)
{
  for(const auto p : msgList)
  {
    std::cerr << p << endl;
  }
}


Now I have the problem that std::string_view causes UB when constructed via null char* (what can happen, there is a lot(!) existing code...).
And I can't change my function to use a variadic template argument list e.g.
template<typename ...T>
void func(const T& ...msgList)

as func is complex (and includes many external dependencies) so I don't want it implemented in a header file.
My idea is now to provide a proxy function which uses a variadic template argument list, check there for char nullptr and call the original initialiser_list based function.
Something like
template<typename ...T>
void proxy_func(const T& ...msgList)
{
  // check msgList for  null char*
  // construct initializer_list
  // call original initializer_list function
}

But I'm lost how to not simply forward the parameter pack into an initialiser_list but to check (and manipulate them) - if this is even possible?

Your comment (optimization, less strlen calls) You could do this same optimization in your function and then you can do the null check as well.  Sometimes the new stuff doesn't work when especially when you need to support old API's.  After you check for null you can get the length of the string and hold onto that and update if you modify just like the view would.

@NathanOliver, yes, you are right, but using std::string_view also allows usage of std::string as parameter - without .c_str() - and already known length. That's why I prefer the string_view version. Incomprehensible why std::string_view does not allow nullptr construction.

Something along these lines perhaps:
template <typename T>
std::string_view MyMakeStringView(T&& arg) {
    return std::string_view{std::forward<T>(arg)};
}

std::string_view MyMakeStringView(const char* s) {
    return !s ? std::string_view{} : std::string_view{s};
}

std::string_view MyMakeStringView(char* s) {
    return !s ? std::string_view{} : std::string_view{s};
}

std::string_view MyMakeStringView(nullptr_t) {
    return std::string_view{};
}

template<typename ...T>
void proxy_func(const T& ...msgList) {
    func({MyMakeStringView(msgList) ...});
}

Demo
